# OpenLayers layer.vector not showing on Mac and Iphone

Tags: javascript, macos, openlayers-3

i want to show the Map of 'Germany' with its borders on a website.
Using Windows 10 and Firefox everything is working fine, but under Mac OS and iPhone the layer.vector is not showing. Any ideas?

```
<script>
  var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(30,144,255,0.2)'
  });
  
  var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#1E90FF',
    width: 2
  });
  
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke
  });
  
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '[URL TO JSON]',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      }),
    style: style
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        vectorLayer

    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.9688, 51.0852]),
      zoom: 5
    })
  });
```

top: Windows 10 + Firefox

bottom: Mac OS + Firefox/Safari

[image]

Comment: no idea? nobody? :/

Comment: What does the console in the web browser say when using Safari on Mac??  My guess is you are running into an error that the other browsers are OK with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget about this question. It was my fault. I got this running with XAMPP locally on my Window 10 PC. The URL was something like localhost/... . Yep, that caused the issue and i was blind and didnt see it for 2 days :D